# How do I stop a mindstorms program?

Tags: lego-mindstorms

How do I stop an EV3 program that is in an infinite loop? (I didn't remove the batteries because it might damage it). I have the stock lego firmware installed.

Comment: Can you share the program that gets stuck? Pressing the back button (top left) should always stop a program. If it does not, there is something very interesting about your program. P.S. Removing the battery will not damage the EV3. It will just cause you to loose any programs that were downloaded since it was turned on.

Comment: I think that is because I wrote my program in C with c4ev3. Maybe the LabView software automatically adds that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out: Hold the back button, left button, and center button. When the screen goes blank release the back button.

If you're using the official LabView, you can just press the back button. This doesn't work when you use c4ev3.

Answer (score 1):

just press the button on the top left simple.

Comment: Nope. Not working. I even tried holding the button. It didn't stop.

Comment: k i'm sorry for misunderstanding your question but i think i can help u as removing the batteries as per my experience just deletes all the programs and nothing happens to the software i  had to do it many times during competitions when the brick crashed or something

Comment: OK, I think I found the answer. You have to hold the back button, left button, and center button. When the screen goes blank release the back button. Done! Source: http://www.legoengineering.com/ev3-gone-wrong-what-to-do-when-your-ev3-stops-working/

Comment: To reset the brick, you only have to hold the back button (top left) and the enter button (center), not the left button.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to use LabView which should come for free with the kit. if you are using C then you need to program in a parallel wait block as an exit contingency which will keep looking for an input by the user or its sensors, say from brick buttons or a touch sensor. then make it terminate the other code in the program and then itself. 
p.s. you can also download the software-firmware package (including LabView) for free on the lego website under 'Downloads' in the mindstorms section